# TWIG outputs incorrect DOM structure

Tags: twig, opencart

In TWIG file I have next line:

```
<p class="itemDescription">{{ product.description }}</p>
```

Naturally, I have to get something like this:

```
<p class="itemDescription">Test string</p>
```

But actually I get this:

```
<p class="itemDescription"></p>
<p>Test string</p>
```

Why so?

---

*PS: It's an Opencart shop, file `www\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.twig`*

Comment: This must be related to the context in which you run this Twig snippet. If you take a look at https://twigfiddle.com/lu6srh, you will see that just using the code you have shown reveals the expected result.

Comment: Try to dump the description, e.g. `{{ dump(product.description) }}`

Comment: @DarkBee PHP gives me error that dump function is undefined... I solved my problem by replacing <p> tag with <div>

Comment: Glad u figured it out, have a look [here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31419&filter_download_id=55&sort=date_added) on how to enable `dump`. Could usefull for future usage

Answer (score 0):

You try code :

```
<p class="itemDescription">{{ product.description |striptags('<p>')}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Product description coming from admin CK editor

it  is HTML formatted text